# Grey shadow on UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar

I'm experiencing a weird problem when I segue to a UIViewController I've made. ViewController B (the one I segue to) has a UIView that slides down using the TransitionCoordinator and constraints, but it shows a grey shadow at the right, like so:

[image]

Once the segue is completely done, it goes back to translucent and displays the blue UIView through the UINavigationBar with a nice blur.

This grey shadow is most likely due to a UIToolBar and UISegmentedControl within that toolbar on the UITableViewController that I segue from. It looks like this:

[image]

I'm using this code together with my UIToolBar:

```
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar {
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```

I've tried to use a TransitionCoordinator to fade out the UIToolBar using it's alpha property, but without success. I've also visited other similar questions on SO, but I haven't gotten anywhere.

The strange thing is that it sometimes work as it should, but I can't figure out why it doesn't always happen nor how to completely remove it.

**UPDATE:**

Xcode view hierarchy:

[image]

View hierarchy in list:

[image]

Transparent navigationBar:

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

Pulling down the UITableView also displays this, how can I attach the UIToolbar? Looks like the delegate methods isn't working propery

[image]

Please help me with this,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I experience the same problem and the cause was that background color of the window was black.

Solved it by setting window color to match view controllers background color in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Answer (score 0):

Once your custom transition completes the outgoing view controller will be removed from its container. This is probably why you are seeing the grey area disappear when the transition completes. Its something in the previous view controller. I can partially replicate your screenshot by creating a UIViewController which a view that has a transparent background. Using the standard animation the grey of the UIWindow's default background color shows through. Since the previous view controller's position is slightly to the right it only shows through on the right side of the nav bar.

The best way to figure out exactly what is happening is to place a breakpoint where you are calling `completeTransition:` or pausing the debugger manually during the animation. You can then use Xcode's View Hierarchy debugger to figure out which view us causing this:

[image]

Once you figure out exactly which view it is you will want to make sure it animates along with your current animation (not after it) and you will want to make sure that `completeTransition:` is called after both animations complete.

Comment: Very nice answer. I find this very strange since when I'm pausing during the transition, I can't see anything that would be the cause of the grey shadow

Comment: Is the background of the appearing view controller clear or is it a solid color?

Comment: It's background color is set to white, also, please take a look at the screenshot I uploaded

Comment: Another trick is to make your nav bar clear. You can do this by setting the background image to a clear image. This will remove the blur and it might be easier to see exactly what is behind your view. Toggling slow animations in the simulator will also help since you can't pause animations very easily.

Comment: Please take a look at my latest screenshot, it certainly looks like it's the tall height of the UIToolbar that is the cause

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm going to have to continue tomorrow, getting very late here. We'll talk more then!

Comment: Have you tried `UIBarPositionTop` instead of `UIBarPositionTopAttached`?

Comment: I'll be sure to try that asap I get to my mac at home, macbook is currently being repaired. Any ideas as to why this is happening like 75% of the time and not always? There are a few times when it works as expected, but the vast majority of attempts results with the undesired behaviour

Comment: tried UIBarPositionTop now, no difference. I also added a new screenshot of the view hierarchy

Comment: When are you assigning the UIToolbar delegate?

Comment: yeah, I actually didn't assign it when I asked the question, but did so earlier today and unfortunately, there was no difference

Comment: I mean are you assigning the delegate on viewDidAppear: ? etc.

Comment: yes, that's right. I assign the delegate of the toolbar on the viewcontrollers viewDidAppear

Comment: You need to assign the delegate earlier, possibly on viewDidLoad:

Comment: tried to do it in viewWillAppear but same result there

Comment: remove Translucent, that seems to solve the grey shadow but my navigation bar line still looks like its loading in. title and buttons appear immediately upon segueing but the bottom line takes awhile